# ASP.NET themes: How to tell if a theme name is valid before setting it as the theme of a page

Tags: asp.net, themes, app-themes

I imagine this would be simple, but I can’t find an answer.

We set the theme of a page based on a query string parameter (like `?theme=theme1`, etc).  I just want to know if there is an easy way to tell the theme name is valid, before setting it, or catching and handling the error if it is invalid.

The error I get if the theme does not exists is:

```
Theme ‘theme1’ cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.
```

I am not sure when the exception is thrown.
All I can think of is searching the folder, but I would think there would be a simpler way.

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, more of a pointer - have you thought of using Profiles to store the user's theme preference instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the theme against the list of theme folders; themes simply uses the folders of the name, so use Directory.Exists within System.IO.